# nginx - codeigniter 404 error for all urls

Tags: php, codeigniter, nginx

I have uploaded my files(Codeigniter Framework) in abcd directory ( url : example.com/abcd ) . All the links inside give 404 error . For removing index.php, I have placed this nginx.conf file in my root directory ( on server : /.../abcd/)
Here is the code for the nginx.conf file :

```
server {  
    server_name example.com/abcd;
    root /..../abcd;

    index index.html index.php index.htm;

    # set expiration of assets to MAX for caching
    location ~* \.(ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)(\?[0-9]+)?$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    location / {
        # Check if a file exists, or route it to index.php.
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    location ~* \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass example.com/abcd;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

}
```

In apache, it was easy using rewrite, i am now stuck with nginx. Please help, I am using nginx for the first time

Comment: Does this config pass the `nginx -t` test. Because the `server_name` is invalid and probably the `fastcgi_pass` statement

Comment: @RichardSmith what should be the correct format for server_name then?

Comment: Read [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html). But you seem to have a `server name` and a `location` mashed together.

Comment: @RichardSmith Actually my main website is bits-bosm.org and what i have made is a subsection. Like my website should be accessible at bits-bosm.org/rouletteadmin . Then what should be the server name?

Comment: The URI `bits-bosm.org/rouletteadmin` will be handled by the same `server { ... }` block that handles `bits-bosm.org`. It is the same server, just a different location. If you read the link I sent, it is all explained.

Comment: @RichardSmith Thanks for your help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122910/discussion-between-mohit-garg-and-richard-smith).

Comment: Actually, [this is a good document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html) for an overview of servers and locations.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code.. taken from 
https://serverfault.com/questions/695521/codeigniter-in-subdirectory-on-nginx-404

```
 location /abcde/ {
        alias  /var/www/abcde/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /abcde/index.php;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_index   index.php;
            fastcgi_pass    backend;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Still not sure why adding the path in try_files work. But it still seems a valid solution. The 404 also don't get logged so debugging is pretty hard!